# JQuery: on submit doesn't work

Tags: jquery

What I am trying is to catch all the form submit events, get the url from the action attribute and use it to send the content of the form to that address using AJAX. So what I need is only one on submit event handler. However I quickly got in trouble as it seems to not be working in IE.

```
$(document).submit(function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This is the code I use for cross-browser testing purpose. It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE. Am I not allowed to set an event listener on document?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at the jQuery API:

> The JavaScript submit event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. However, scripts that rely on event delegation with the submit event will work consistently across browsers as of jQuery 1.4, which has normalized the event's behavior. ([api.jquery.com/submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/))

The `submit` event does not bubble in Internet Explorer, so the `document` element will never be notified of `submit` events. jQuery will normalise this for you, but only if you use event delegation. This is not difficult to do, and in fact may make your code nicer, if there is more complexity to it:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This keeps the advantages of binding to the `document` (e.g. capturing events on elements that don't yet exist), while making it possible in IE. Note that `this`, within the event handler, is now the `form` element, not the `document`.

Comment: In my case it is still not working in IE. The form is pulled using ajax.

Comment: @Andrew Could you provide a simplified, non-working example, then?

Comment: not really, but I will give an example as clear as possible. If I apply it to a present from the begging form it is working. As soon as I start to pull the form with ajax, the event handler doesn't work anymore. This is some code that works (register the event handler after pulling the form): $('.dialogContext').load('/add/addprojectform', function() {    
    $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
     e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: @lonesomeday snippet should work, I've used a similar script to bind an event handler to the form.someClass elements dinamically loaded. You could try also binding it to body or to a div which holds the dinamically loaded forms.

Comment: DOES NOT WORK for delegated events.  Must attach events directly to the form element itself (that's actually mentioned in the documentation, but without an explanation as to why).  By the time the delegated handler runs, the form has already posted to the server as of Chrome 46, so there's no chance to call preventDefault.

Comment: @Triynko I think that might well be a change in behaviour since this answer was written.

Comment: This did not work for me because I had an ID attribute on the submit button. Now its just a simple `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>`.

Answer (score 3):

Attach the listener to your forms

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: well, the reason I registered the event on document is because I am loading the form using ajax. So I would have to register the event after each pulling of the data, right?

Comment: yes, you're right and here is how you can get the action URL - http://jsfiddle.net/qSB4V/1/

Comment: @Andrew: In that case using jQuery `on()` to bind should do the trick as it attaches to future elements when using the appropriate override.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl No, it doesn't. Have a look at my answer for how to do this correctly.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl It's the difference between `$(document).on` (binds to the document) and `$('form').on` (binds to the form). `on` doesn't always use event delegation, only if you tell it to

Comment: @lonesomeday I replaced on with delegate and still it ignores the on submit event handler.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I suggested to use the correct override of `on()` to bind which you are doing. So not sure what the difference is. I never said to use `on()` on the form as that obviously would not include future elements. Anyway, your answer should work so all is good I guess.

Comment: If you use event delegation, it seems, you cannot cancel the submit event.  It's only cancellable if you bind it directly to the form element.  For example, if you say `$(document).on('submit','.my-form-class',function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;})`, the form will still be submitted, but not if you say `$('.my-form-class').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;});`, although in the second case your form element must already exist.  This is a terrible bug.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```