# submit event does not fire if submit initiated programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, event-handling

I have a HTML form with button:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="MyForm">
<input type="hidden" name="Field1" value="Value1" />
<input type="hidden" name="Field2" value="Value2" />
<input type="submit" name="name" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I have event handler for submit attached to Window:

```
window.onsubmit = function()
{
    alert("Submit happening!");
};
```

This event handler fires properly if I click "Submit" button.
However events never works when submit is triggered programmatically from javascript:

```
$("#MyForm")[0].submit();
```

How to catch submit event handler when it was initiated by Javascript, not by User click?
I tried to subscribe for Form event using Jquery or AddEventListener - does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should jQuery's $(form).submit(); not trigger onSubmit within the form tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because you shouldn't just use the `submit` function, but `trigger` the submit like:

```
$("#MyForm").trigger('submit');
```

Answer (score 12):

Browsers don't fire the form's `onsubmit` handler when you manually call `form.submit()`.

jQuery also <strike>mimicks</strike> used to mimick that (see this ["wontfix" "bug" report](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906022921/http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4930)).

See also:

- [Should jQuery's $(form).submit(); not trigger onSubmit within the form tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag)
- [JQuery: on submit doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172811/jquery-on-submit-doesnt-work)

Comment: That's interesting, I'll try to find out what jquery is doing differently.

Comment: Why would an infinite loop be created ?

Comment: @Rishabh Because the best place to call submit is the onsubmit event handler.

Comment: @bfavaretto sorry but I am still confused. you would'nt call `form.submit()` from inside the `onsubmit` handler. The OP's example doesn't do that. So a call to `form.submit()` should ideally just trigger the event handler and be done with it.

Comment: @Rishabh You are right, that's just one of several possible reasons to this behavior. Another, stronger reason is that user code usually doesn't fire events. If you change an input's value, it doesn't trigger `onchange`. Anyway, this decision dates many years back, and I couldn't find much record of how the decision was taken.

Comment: I put the reasoning into an article here which makes more sense - http://codetheory.in/javascript-fire-onsubmit-by-calling-form-submit/ - basically this behaviour actually adheres to the HTML form validation specs.