# onsubmit not called via onclick script

Tags: javascript, onclick, onsubmit

I have looked carefully through other questions to find an answer, and I haven't had any luck, so if this has already been asked and I've missed it, my apologies in advance.  I have a very simple page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setFormField(data) {
        document.getElementById('searchTextField').value = data;
        document.getElementById("lookupForm").submit();
    }

    function formSubmit() {
        alert('in');
        var proceed = false;
        return proceed;
    }           
</script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" id="lookupForm" name="lookupForm" onSubmit="return formSubmit();">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="searchTextField" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href="#" onclick="return setFormField('sample text')">click me</a>
</body>
```

The idea is that when you click the "click me" link, it enters some data into the form and then submits the form, which should then call the onSubmit script - but the formSubmit() function never gets called - the form just submits itself.

Why doesn't the formSubmit() function get called?  Seems like it should...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [submit event does not fire if submit initiated programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774821/submit-event-does-not-fire-if-submit-initiated-programatically)

Comment: seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/TEpgc/

Comment: @BeNdErR — Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BeNdErR - Not for me either.

Comment: if you click the `submit` button in the fiddle, do you see the alert `in`? @user3009485 do you get any error in the console?