# rails 4 form submit as div, validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a problem when trying to submit a form with a div (instead of a f.submit button)

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "submit_user"}, html: {id: "user_submit", class: "form"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :first name, :required => true, :placeholder => 'first name', :autocomplete => :off %>
     <%= f.text_field :last name, :required => true, :placeholder => 'last name', :autocomplete => :off %>
     <div id="submituser" class="some very fancy css here" onclick = "document.forms['user_submit'].submit();">
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the form **is sent**, but **without the validations** (causing it to send blank first and last name if nothing is entered)

note that when using

```
<% f.submit "submit" %>
```

validations do work.

Thanks

Comment: You could make such validation on server side too.. :)

Comment: yes, that's true, but after 2 hours of frustrations. i don't want any of your shenanigan ides ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here:
[Difference between handling $(“form”).submit or an  click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785241/difference-between-handling-form-submit-or-an-input-type-submit-click-e)

And i quote @Giovanni Sferro:

> The click callback is called only if the user actually click on the submit button. But there are cases in which you would submit the form automatically by javascript, in that case the click callback is not fired while the submit callback is. I would recommend to use always the submit for validation and intrinsic action of the form, while using the click callback for animation or other things related to the action of clicking on the button.

so my (working) code looks like this:

```
<div id="submituser" class="some very fancy css here" onclick = '$("#user_submit input[type=\"submit\"]").click();'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `document.forms['user_submit'].submit();` does not trigger the submit event, so You have to launch validation manually. But what is the point of using `div` instead of `button`? You could style a button with `some very fancy css here` too. OR make a 'hidden' submit button and add `onclick = "document.form.button.click()"` to `div` :-)

Comment: Thanks @IvanSelivanov, but i tested it, and it did not work (still skips validation)
for your questions:
the `document.forms['user_submit'].submit();` does fire the submit form, but skips the validation part of it.
for the style issue, i have a very complex button that is created from many layers of divs, that's why a submit button is not enough for me.

Comment: @amitben, I guess the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774821/submit-event-does-not-fire-if-submit-initiated-programatically

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll need to further investigate it.